# Scala to fetch the details from the oracle table and fire the query in hive table

Tags: database, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to connect to oracle database and for that I have to have use the pure scala connection not the spark one. So I have written the connection code for oracle database.

Now the main headache is I have a column in the oracle table which has a select query written for the each row(somewhat the table has the metadata).
I need to take the query written in each column and fire it which will be on hive table and stored the result of query in dataframe. I am not sure what approach to achive the above problem.

Oracle table data

[image]

I am able to connect to the oracle table using pure scala connection .I need to fetch the query col data and fire it. The query result I need to store in dataframe for further processing.

Connection Code:-

```
    object ScalaJdbcConnectSelect {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // connect to the database named "mysql" on the localhost
    val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql"
    val username = "root"
    val password = "root"

    
    var connection:Connection = null

    try {
      // make the connection
      Class.`enter code here`forName(driver)
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)

      // create the statement, and run the select query
      val statement = connection.createStatement()
      val resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query)`
```

Comment: Show us your connection code? What do you get back from your connection/query? A `java.sql.ResultSet`?

Comment: I have added the connection code in the post. Ia m geeting back the java result set from statment.executequery.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to Oracle from Spark, and you should do [that](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html), because otherwise you will have to bring all the data sequentially into some intermediate storage, before reading it with Spark, and that's pretty wasteful compared to having multiple connections to the database retrieving data in parallel.

```scala
// Set the variables server, port, service
val url = s"jdbc:oracle:thin:@$server:$port:$service"

// Add odbc6.jar via --driver-class-path and --jars during spark-shell/submit 
val reader = spark.read.format("jdbc")
  .option("url", url)
  .option("user", user)
  .option("password", password)
  .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

// Note the use of partitionColumn is necessary to create multiple connections 
// from the workers
val df = reader.option("dbtable", "db.table")
               .option("partitionColumn", "col1")
               .load
val dfWithQuery = reader.option("dbtable", "(SELECT a, b, c FROM t1) AS tbl1")
                  .option("partitionColumn", "a")
                  .load
```

You get your result `df` first and then can can collect the query column, looping through and adding the collected query to the `reader` to create a new `DataFrame`.

If you insist to use your method, then you already have a `ResultSet`[2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), . You simply have to get your column while you iterate through the rows and then use the query with your `Connection`.

```scala
// ^ Your code above, Connection already exists
while (resultSet.next()){
  try {
    val queryValue = resultSet.getString("query")
    val queryResultSet = statement.executeQuery(queryValue)
    while (queryResultSet){
      // Do stuff with your newly queried ResultSet
    }
  }
}
```

You can see how multilevel `try catch` is not very pretty.

If you want you can create a `Dataset` out of the `ResultSet`, but note that this necessitates that you load the whole `RestulSet` into the driver's memory first and if the data is big you might run out.

```scala
def resultSetToSpark[T](rs: ResultSet, f: ResultSet => T, 
                        spark: SparkSession, encoder: Encoder[T]): Dataset[T] = {
  val data: Seq[T] = Iterator.continually(rs.next, rs)
    .takeWhile(_._1).map{
      case (_,rs) => f(rs)
    }.toList

  spark.createDataset(data)(encoder)
}
```

Note, you have to provide a function which gets a single row from the `ResultSet` and instantiates a `class` out of the retrieved values, and an encoder of your class. Below is an example.

```scala
case class Potato(a: String, b: String, c: String)

def parseResultSet(rs: ResultSet): Potato = Potato(
 rs.getString("a"), rs.getString("b"), rs.getString("c")
)

import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}
val encoder: Encoder[Potato] =  Encoders.product[Potato]

// Use like this
val dfFromRS = resultSetToSpark(resultSet, parseResultSet, spark, encoder)
```

So the best approach really is to use Spark's `DataFrameReader` and have Spark workers make multiple connections to the database, but that really only matters if the data in question can cause the driver to run out of memory.

---

You can always get the list of all queries like this.

```scala
case class Query(statement: String)
implicit val queryEncoder: Encoder[Query] = Encoders.product[Query]
val queryDs = resultSetToSpark(rs)(rs => Message(rs.getString("query")))(spark, queryEncoder)
val queryList = queryDs.collect.toList
val df1 = spark.sql(queryList.head) // get a DataFrame from the first query in the list
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail reply .The query col has the  sql statements and that I need to run on the hive table..How can i achieve that. For connection to oracle I am using the pure scala connection not the spark connection.

Comment: @Saurabh So what do you want to do with the Hive tables as you access them?

Comment: My problem statement is that I have one oracle table in that col_1 has the queries. Queries needs to be fired on hive table and the result of query I got from hive table needs to store in dataframe for each query which is going to be fired.

Comment: I made the connection to oracle table and fetch the data from table in resultset.Net I nned to fire the query on hive table

Comment: Maybe I've over-complicated this. Do you know that you can use `spark.sql(query)` to get a `DataFrame`? Or do you want a list of all the queries before you do something with them?

Comment: I want for each query to be fired on hive and create a separate dataframe for that. Like  for first row query res will store in df1 and for 2nd row query df2. Is there an easy way to perform this.

Comment: @Saurabh, I added a little in the end of the answer to explain how to get the List of queries. You can use the list elements to get DataFrames using `spark.sql(query)`.